# Please retry: error (invalid JSON mapping) for Json

Tags: json, apache-drill

```
{
    "type": "file",
    "enabled": true,
    "connection": "classpath:///",
    "config": null,
    "workspaces": {
        "jsonfiles": {
            "location": "C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\JSON",
            "writable": true,
            "defaultInputFormat": null
        }
    },
    "formats": {
        "json": {
            "type": "json",
            "extensions": [
                "json"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error below when updating the configuration of storage plugin:

> Please retry: error (invalid JSON mapping)

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, in your json data location path is causing error. JSON causes parsing error with backslash.

Use `\\` instead of `\` as below.

`"location": "C:\\Users\\mypc\\Desktop\\JSON"`

Comment: I'm facing same issue ```{
    "type": "jdbc",
    "driver": "com.simba.couchbase.jdbc41.Driver",
    "url": "jdbc:couchbase://localhost:8093/LifeAsia;AuthMech=1",
    "CredFile":"C:/Program%20Files/apache-drill-1.16.0/jars/3rdparty/Couchbase_JDBC_Credentials.json",
    "enabled": true
}```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json in invalid. Use ESCAPE SEQUENCE in the location key of your JSON to resolve the issue.

Try rewriting your JSON as:

```
  {
    "type": "file",
    "enabled": true,
    "connection": "classpath:///",
    "config": null,
    "workspaces": {
        "jsonfiles": {
            "location": "C:\\Users\\mypc\\Desktop\\JSON",
            "writable": true,
            "defaultInputFormat": null
        }
    },
    "formats": {
        "json": {
            "type": "json",
            "extensions": [
                "json"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```